# Visual Studio 2015 - Javascript ES6 not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, ecmascript-6

I am playing around with VS 2015 JavaScript/NodeJS IDE and I plan to use ES6 as the language style for JavaScript, however I am noticing that Visual Studio is not recognizing the ES6 (even though I read on various web sites that VS should recognize ES6).

Does anyone know how to make VS 2015 play nice (both in syntax highlighting, intellisense, etc) with ES6?

[image: es6-errors]

I also modified the file extension to be .JSX and .ES6 in case that would help VS pick up on it. No luck...

Comment: Did you already look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/31544470/218196 ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want IntelliSense for ES6 in a nodejs project, then you need to turn on a particular setting.

Open Tools → Options → Text editor → Node.js → IntelliSense and select the *ES6 IntelliSense Preview* checkbox.

In the December 2015 version of the tools, there is a link to [additional notes](https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools/wiki/ES6-IntelliSense-Preview-in-NTVS-1.1) about the prerequisites, such as having to install TypeScript for Visual Studio 2015 so that ES6 IntelliSense works.

Comment: In my installation there is no Node.js option section

Comment: @Shawn, it's actually at `tools > options> text editor > node.js > intellisense`. You'll have to install [typescript 1.6](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593) in order to enable ES6 intellisense.

Answer (score 3):

@Shawn, in order to enable the Node.js options (and ES6 IntelliSense) you need to install the Visual Studio NodeJS Tools: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/node-js-vs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try install TypeScript for Visual Studio 2015 and restart VS2015.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593

I resolve many problem with this.