# Visual Studio 2015 JSX/ES2015 syntax highlighting with babel

Tags: babeljs, reactjs, visual-studio-2015

**What i am tring to do:**

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34110461/1641172) answer, i am seeing if i can swap out the `react-tools` transformer for the `babel-core` transformer with presets for `react`, `es2015` and `stage-1`.

VS2015 community uses react tools on a node server to transpile the code on the fly, the `nodeJs` `server.js` file is located at:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\react-server`

The following lines in the `transformJsxFromPost` function do the tranformation and return the `elementMap` to visual studio:

```
var transformed = reactTools.transformWithDetails(code, { elementMap: true });
result = { elementMappings: transformed.elementMappings };
```

When you start VS, this creates a temp folder in your local app data and starts a node server at the following location:

`%localappdata%\Temp\{most-recent-generated-guid-folder}`

**Where i have got so far:**
The visual studio `External\react-tools\` folder has a `node_modules` folder, so i npm installed the following there:

```
npm install babel-core --save-dev
npm install babel-preset-es2015 --save-dev
npm install babel-preset-react --save-dev
npm install babel-preset-stage-1 --save-dev
```

Added the following to the top of the `server.js` file:

```
var babel = require('babel-core');
```

And replaced the lines in `transformJsxFromPost` mentioned above for the following lines:

```
var transformed = babel.transform(code, {sourceMaps: "inline"});
result = { elementMappings: transformed.map };
```

At this stage, restart visual studio and it works, i get a sourceMap returned (admittedly not in the same format as the `react-tools` elementMap yet).

**Where i am stuck:**
As soon as i try to get babel to use presets, i am getting errors. So when i change the first line to:

```
var transformed = babel.transform(code, {sourceMaps: "inline", presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-1']});
```

I get the error:

> JSX Parser: Couldn't find preset \"es2015\" relative to directory
>   \"C:\\Users\\

The presets are all dependencies in the `package.json` file in the react-server folder, and it's not having any issues with babel, so why is it looking in the temp directory for the plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to pass the actual presets to the function in this case instead of importing them and passing their name by string like in webpack.

I added the following imports:

```
var es2015 = require('babel-preset-es2015');
var react = require('babel-preset-react');
var stage1 = require('babel-preset-stage-1');
```

and changed

```
presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage1']
```

to

```
presets: [es2015, react, stage1]
```

I have added an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36321109/1641172) to a similar question.