# Visual Studio 2015 doesn't support es6 syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-2015, ecmascript-6, resharper

I'm working on a web project, using react with es6 for the client side and asp.net for the server side and I want to be able to work on visual studio 2015 update 2 which supports es6 and jsx.

My problem is that visual studio always gives syntax error when I'm writing es6 and jsx:

[image]

I searched all over google and all I found is 2 solutions which can be found here: 
[Visual Studio 2015 JSX/ES2015 syntax highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097915/visual-studio-2015-jsx-es2015-syntax-highlighting)

I tried both of the solution, and they did help but I still have syntax errors, as showed in the first picture.

The only option to completely solve my problem is to tell vs to ignore syntax errors in js and jsx files :

[image]

But I still want a better solution that shows me relevant syntax errors.

Comment: I suppose you should enable the typescript compiler.

Comment: Is there a requirement to use Visual Studio? VSCode handles ES6 really well and it is free.