# Restore Visual Studio react-server folder

Tags: visual-studio, reactjs, visual-studio-2015

I was working on this problem: 
[Visual Studio 2015 JSX/ES2015 syntax highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097915/visual-studio-2015-jsx-es2015-syntax-highlighting)

But accidentally wiped out the react-server folder:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\react-server

How do I restore it?  If not restorable, would someone be kind enough to zip up the folder and send it to me?

Answer (score 0):

Just kidding, luckily had another machine with VS2015 installed, grabbed the folder from there, attaching here for posterity.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_ptsncEBit5YVlUNU9xM0U3VG8/view?usp=sharing