# React and ES6 syntax in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-2015, ecmascript-6, intellisense

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.

I am using `React` with new language features in `*.jsx` files, but Visual Studio get lot of syntax errors. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097915/visual-studio-2015-jsx-es2015-syntax-highlighting) solution, but it doesn't work for me.

[image]

`*.js` highlighter supports new features, but doesn't support `React` syntax:

[image]

It there any solution to get good syntax highlighting for React EC6 in Visual Studio?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2015 JSX/ES2015 syntax highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097915/visual-studio-2015-jsx-es2015-syntax-highlighting)