# state, props and setState are being underlined by red

Tags: reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

I am using Visual Studio 2015 to work on a React JS project.

There are no errors raised while I run buld.

But state, props and setState are being underlined by red.

Please suggest a solution if anyone knows about It.

Comment: on putting cursor over it,what are text shown?

Comment: hope this helps, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097915/visual-studio-2015-jsx-es2015-syntax-highlighting/

Comment: Do you mean you're seeing linter errors? It's most likely that Visual Studio doesn't properly know how to parse `this`. Honestly I would suggest that you use a more modern code editor for Javascript like [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) or Atom.

Comment: the text is just undelined red. No lint errors