# how to fix Resharper warning for importing class in es6

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-2017, resharper

i followed [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097915/visual-studio-2015-jsx-es2015-syntax-highlighting/41996170#41996170) and now my ReSharper doesn't make much noise about the react syntax, but there is one annoying warning that is shown for class names

[image]

or for class names

[image]

or Promise is a javascript feature, but i get warning as global variable warning thing

[image]

is there any solution for these?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

[image]

or if you want validate `EcmaScript 2016`

[image]

Comment: this way I just turnoff intellisense for js and jsx, thanks but not the solution i'm looking for

Comment: I had to enable 'Experimental' features instead of EcmaScript 2016 to get rid of react import warnings. Unfortunately I'm getting warnings about my html layout/jsx.