# React (jsx) support in Visual Studio 2017 (not VS Code)

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-2017

Is there any way to get any support for jsx-syntax in visual studio? preferably for both .js- and .jsx-files

All I get now is squiggly lines over the shop, so anything better than that would be great

I dont want another IDE just for my react code. (ie, I know about VS Code.)

Is there any way to get any support for jsx-syntax in visual studio 2017?

Comment: in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097915/visual-studio-2015-jsx-es2015-syntax-highlighting one suggest you could set Typescript as the editor on .jsx files, you could change that for js files too but maybe that isnt what you want.

Comment: Nice! Please post same thing in an answer so I get set it as correct answer and youll get the credits